# problem with setters and getters

Tags: python

Hi I'm Trying to work with setters and getters in python for one class and I want to use the setter with other instruction, so when setting the property value, the setter do more than only assign the value to the property. Maybe I'm confused on how the setter and getter work. Here is an example:

```
class test:
      self.x = None

      @property
      def var(self):
           return self.x

      @var.setter
      def var(self, value):
           print("Assigning Value")
           self.x = value

 v = test()
 v.var = "hello"
```

So what I'm trying to do in this example is to print "Assigning Value" when x value is assigned, but so far Isn't working.

My question is. Do I'm doing something wrong?,Do I miss something?, or that's not the way setters and getters work?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
class test:
```

To:

```
class test(object):
```

In Python 2.x you can only use the descriptors if inheriting from object. (Its a backwards compatibility thing). Fortunately, this has been resolved in Python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

At this point, there is no self:

```
class test:
      self.x = None
#     ^^^^^ BAD
```

change it to either set in the initializer:

```
class test:
     def __init__(self):
         self.x = None
```

or use a class attribute normally.

```
class test:
      x = None
```

If you aren't sure which, go with the first; it'll confuse you less to use that pattern until you are more confident about the difference.

Comment: You were right, I give a bad example, and I miss the initialization method. Thanks